# SQL Server trigger doesn't work upon inserting record

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, triggers

I have this code that inserts a record in the `LABOR_TICKET` table successfully, but I don't fully understand about triggers and I can't figure out why a part of trigger doesn't work to update the table OPERATION.

My code:

```
protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=infor2;Initial Catalog=xxxxxx;Integrated Security=True");

    SqlCommand insert = new SqlCommand(@"insert into labor_ticket
                                                        (TRANSACTION_ID,
                                                        WORKORDER_BASE_ID,
                                                        OPERATION_SEQ_NO,
                                                        TYPE,
                                                        SETUP_COMPLETED,
                                                        EMPLOYEE_ID,
                                                        DEPARTMENT_ID,
                                                        RESOURCE_ID,
                                                        HOURS_WORKED,
                                                        MULTIPLIER_1,
                                                        MULTIPLIER_2,
                                                        GOOD_QTY,
                                                        BAD_QTY,
                                                        TRANSACTION_DATE,
                                                        POSTING_CANDIDATE,
                                                        INDIRECT_CODE,
                                                        ACT_LABOR_COST,
                                                        ACT_BURDEN_COST,
                                                        CREATE_DATE)
                                                        VALUES(@TRANSACTION_ID,
                                                        @WORKORDER_BASE_ID,
                                                        @OPERATION_SEQ_NO,
                                                        @TYPE,
                                                        @SETUP_COMPLETED,
                                                        @EMPLOYEE_ID,
                                                        @DEPARTMENT_ID,
                                                        @RESOURCE_ID,
                                                        @HOURS_WORKED,
                                                        @MULTIPLIER_1,
                                                        @MULTIPLIER_2,
                                                        @GOOD_QTY,
                                                        @BAD_QTY,
                                                        @TRANSACTION_DATE,
                                                        @POSTING_CANDIDATE,
                                                        @INDIRECT_CODE,
                                                        @ACT_LABOR_COST,
                                                        @ACT_BURDEN_COST,
                                                        @CREATE_DATE)", conn);

    insert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TRANSACTION_ID", 78535);
    insert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@WORKORDER_BASE_ID", "W14935");
    insert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OPERATION_SEQ_NO", 20);
    insert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TYPE", "R");
    insert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SETUP_COMPLETED", "Y");
    insert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EMPLOYEE_ID", "EZ0022");
    insert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DEPARTMENT_ID", "Operations");
    insert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RESOURCE_ID", "WC0VIBRA");
    insert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@HOURS_WORKED", 1.50);
    insert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MULTIPLIER_1", 1.00);
    insert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MULTIPLIER_2", 1.00);
    insert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@GOOD_QTY", 7.0);
    insert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BAD_QTY", 0.0000);
    insert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TRANSACTION_DATE", "2016-11-04 01:00:00.000");
    insert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@POSTING_CANDIDATE", "Y");
    insert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@INDIRECT_CODE", "X");
    insert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ACT_LABOR_COST", 1.00);
    insert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ACT_BURDEN_COST", 1.00);
    insert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CREATE_DATE", "2016-11-04 02:30:00.000");

    try
    {
            conn.Open();
            insert.ExecuteNonQuery();
            Response.Write("labor ticket record inserted !");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
            Response.Write("Error: " + ex.Message);
            conn.Close();
    }
}
```

This is the trigger associated for the `LABOR_TICKET` table:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF
GO

ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[INSERT_LABOR_TICKET] 
ON [dbo].[LABOR_TICKET] 
FOR INSERT 
AS
    SET NOCOUNT ON  

    DECLARE @nRcd INT  
    DECLARE @CostingStdLabor CHAR  
    DECLARE @CostingMethod CHAR  
    DECLARE @TYPE CHAR  
    DECLARE @MULTIPLIER_1 DEC(5,3)  
    DECLARE @MULTIPLIER_2 DEC(5,3)  
    DECLARE @POSTING_CANDIDATE CHAR  
    DECLARE @SETUP_COMPLETED CHAR  
    DECLARE @TRANSACTION_ID INT  
    DECLARE @WORKORDER_TYPE CHAR  
    DECLARE @WORKORDER_BASE_ID VARCHAR(30)  
    DECLARE @WORKORDER_LOT_ID VARCHAR(3)  
    DECLARE @WORKORDER_SPLIT_ID VARCHAR(3)  
    DECLARE @WORKORDER_SUB_ID VARCHAR(3)  
    DECLARE @OPERATION_SEQ_NO SMALLINT  
    DECLARE @CALC_END_QTY DEC(14,4)  
    DECLARE @COMPLETED_QTY DEC(14,4)  
    DECLARE @EST_LABOR_COST DEC(15,2)  
    DECLARE @EST_BURDEN_COST DEC(15,2)  
    DECLARE @STATUS CHAR  
    DECLARE @CLOSE_DATE DATETIME  
    DECLARE @NewCompletedQty DEC(14,4)  
    DECLARE @QtyOver DEC(14,4)  
    DECLARE @GOOD_QTY DEC(14,4)  
    DECLARE @Ratio1 DEC(14,4)  
    DECLARE @Ratio2 DEC(14,4)  
    DECLARE @TotalLaborCost DEC(15,2)  
    DECLARE @TotalBurdenCost DEC(15,2)  
    DECLARE @LaborCost DEC(15,2)  
    DECLARE @BurdenCost DEC(15,2)  
    DECLARE @HOURS_WORKED DEC(7,2)  
    DECLARE @HOURLY_COST DEC(15,2)  
    DECLARE @BAD_QTY DEC(14,4)  
    DECLARE @UNIT_COST DEC(15,6)  
    DECLARE @BURDEN_PERCENT DEC(6,3)  
    DECLARE @BURDEN_PER_HR DEC(15,2)  
    DECLARE @BURDEN_PER_UNIT DEC(15,6)  
    DECLARE @BUR_PER_OPERATION DEC(15,2)  
    DECLARE @ACT_LABOR_COST DEC(15,2)  
    DECLARE @ACT_BURDEN_COST DEC(15,2)  
    DECLARE @SetupHrs DEC(7,2)  
    DECLARE @RunHrs DEC(7,2)  
    DECLARE @TRANSACTION_DATE DATETIME  
    SELECT @nRcd = 0  

    DECLARE LABOR_TICKET_INS CURSOR LOCAL FOR  
     SELECT  
     TRANSACTION_ID,  
     TYPE, MULTIPLIER_1, MULTIPLIER_2, POSTING_CANDIDATE, SETUP_COMPLETED, ISNULL(HOURS_WORKED, 0),  
     WORKORDER_TYPE, WORKORDER_BASE_ID, WORKORDER_LOT_ID, WORKORDER_SPLIT_ID, WORKORDER_SUB_ID, OPERATION_SEQ_NO,  
     ISNULL(GOOD_QTY, 0), ISNULL(HOURLY_COST, 0), ISNULL(BAD_QTY, 0), ISNULL(UNIT_COST, 0),  
     ISNULL(BURDEN_PERCENT, 0), ISNULL(BURDEN_PER_HR, 0), ISNULL(BURDEN_PER_UNIT, 0),  
     ISNULL(BUR_PER_OPERATION,0), TRANSACTION_DATE  
     FROM INSERTED  
    OPEN LABOR_TICKET_INS  
    FETCH LABOR_TICKET_INS INTO  
     @TRANSACTION_ID,  
     @TYPE, @MULTIPLIER_1, @MULTIPLIER_2, @POSTING_CANDIDATE, @SETUP_COMPLETED, @HOURS_WORKED,  
     @WORKORDER_TYPE, @WORKORDER_BASE_ID, @WORKORDER_LOT_ID, @WORKORDER_SPLIT_ID, @WORKORDER_SUB_ID, @OPERATION_SEQ_NO,  
     @GOOD_QTY, @HOURLY_COST, @BAD_QTY, @UNIT_COST,  
     @BURDEN_PERCENT, @BURDEN_PER_HR, @BURDEN_PER_UNIT, @BUR_PER_OPERATION, @TRANSACTION_DATE  
    WHILE (@nRcd = 0 and @@FETCH_STATUS <> -1)  
    BEGIN  
     select @CostingStdLabor = costing_std_labor, @CostingMethod = costing_method from APPLICATION_GLOBAL  
     select  
     @CALC_END_QTY = calc_end_qty,  
     @COMPLETED_QTY = completed_qty,  
     @EST_LABOR_COST = est_atl_lab_cost,  
     @EST_BURDEN_COST = est_atl_bur_cost,  
     @STATUS = status,  
     @CLOSE_DATE = close_date  
     from operation  
     where  
     workorder_type = @WORKORDER_TYPE  
     and workorder_base_id = @WORKORDER_BASE_ID  
     and workorder_lot_id = @WORKORDER_LOT_ID  
     and workorder_split_id = @WORKORDER_SPLIT_ID  
     and workorder_sub_id = @WORKORDER_SUB_ID  
     and sequence_no = @OPERATION_SEQ_NO  
     SELECT @NewCompletedQty = @COMPLETED_QTY + @GOOD_QTY  
     SELECT @QtyOver = @NewCompletedQty - @COMPLETED_QTY  
     If @CostingMethod = 'S' And @CostingStdLabor = 'Q' And @TYPE != 'I'  
     BEGIN  
     SELECT @Ratio1 = 0  
     SELECT @Ratio2 = 0  
     If @CALC_END_QTY != 0  
     BEGIN  
     SELECT @Ratio1 = @NewCompletedQty / @CALC_END_QTY  
     SELECT @Ratio2 = @QtyOver / @CALC_END_QTY  
     END  
     SELECT @TotalLaborCost = @EST_LABOR_COST * @Ratio1  
     SELECT @TotalBurdenCost = @EST_BURDEN_COST * @Ratio1  
     SELECT @LaborCost = @EST_LABOR_COST * @Ratio2  
     SELECT @BurdenCost = @EST_BURDEN_COST * @Ratio2  
     END  
     Else  
     BEGIN  
     SELECT @LaborCost = (@HOURS_WORKED * @HOURLY_COST * @MULTIPLIER_1 * @MULTIPLIER_2) + ((@GOOD_QTY + @BAD_QTY) * @UNIT_COST)  
     SELECT @BurdenCost = (@LaborCost * (@BURDEN_PERCENT/100)) + (@HOURS_WORKED * @BURDEN_PER_HR) + ((@GOOD_QTY + @BAD_QTY) * @BURDEN_PER_UNIT) + @BUR_PER_OPERATION  
     END  
     If (@TYPE = 'I')  
     SELECT @POSTING_CANDIDATE = 'Y'  
     SELECT @ACT_LABOR_COST = @LaborCost + .005  
     SELECT @ACT_BURDEN_COST = @BurdenCost + .005  
     UPDATE LABOR_TICKET SET  
     POSTING_CANDIDATE = @POSTING_CANDIDATE,  
     ACT_LABOR_COST = @LaborCost,  
     ACT_BURDEN_COST = @BurdenCost  
     WHERE TRANSACTION_ID = @TRANSACTION_ID  
     If @TYPE != 'I'  
     BEGIN  
     If @TYPE = 'R'  
     BEGIN  
     SELECT @SETUP_COMPLETED = 'Y'  
     SELECT @SetupHrs = 0  
     SELECT @RunHrs = @HOURS_WORKED  
     END  
     Else  
     BEGIN  
     SELECT @SetupHrs = @HOURS_WORKED  
     SELECT @RunHrs = 0  
     END  
     If @NewCompletedQty >= @CALC_END_QTY  
     BEGIN  
     SELECT @STATUS = 'C'  
     SELECT @CLOSE_DATE = @TRANSACTION_DATE  
     END  
     If @CostingMethod = 'S' And @CostingStdLabor = 'Q'  
     update OPERATION set  
     act_atl_lab_cost = round( @TotalLaborCost, 2 ),  
     act_atl_bur_cost = round( @TotalBurdenCost, 2 ),  
     completed_qty = completed_qty + @GOOD_QTY,  
     deviated_qty = deviated_qty + @BAD_QTY,  
     act_setup_hrs = act_setup_hrs + @SetupHrs,  
     act_run_hrs = act_run_hrs + @RunHrs,  
     setup_completed = @SETUP_COMPLETED,  
     status = @STATUS,  
     close_date = @CLOSE_DATE  
     where  
     workorder_type = @WORKORDER_TYPE  
     and workorder_base_id = @WORKORDER_BASE_ID  
     and workorder_lot_id = @WORKORDER_LOT_ID  
     and workorder_split_id = @WORKORDER_SPLIT_ID  
     and workorder_sub_id = @WORKORDER_SUB_ID  
     and sequence_no = @OPERATION_SEQ_NO  
     Else  
     update OPERATION set  
     act_atl_lab_cost = act_atl_lab_cost + round(@LaborCost, 2),  
     act_atl_bur_cost = act_atl_bur_cost + round(@BurdenCost, 2),  
     completed_qty = completed_qty + @GOOD_QTY,  
     deviated_qty = deviated_qty + @BAD_QTY,  
     act_setup_hrs = act_setup_hrs + @SetupHrs,  
     act_run_hrs = act_run_hrs + @RunHrs,  
     setup_completed = @SETUP_COMPLETED,  
     status = @STATUS,  
     close_date = @CLOSE_DATE  
     where  
     workorder_type = @WORKORDER_TYPE  
     and workorder_base_id = @WORKORDER_BASE_ID  
     and workorder_lot_id = @WORKORDER_LOT_ID  
     and workorder_split_id = @WORKORDER_SPLIT_ID  
     and workorder_sub_id = @WORKORDER_SUB_ID  
     and sequence_no = @OPERATION_SEQ_NO  
     END  
     UPDATE WORK_ORDER SET DESIRED_QTY = DESIRED_QTY * 1 WHERE type = @WORKORDER_TYPE  
     and base_id = @WORKORDER_BASE_ID  
     and lot_id = @WORKORDER_LOT_ID  
     and split_id = @WORKORDER_SPLIT_ID  
     and sub_id = '0'  
     update EQUIP_PM_SCHEDULE set INVOICE_FLAG = 'R'  
     where  
     workorder_type = @WORKORDER_TYPE  
     AND workorder_base_id = @WORKORDER_BASE_ID  
     AND workorder_lot_id = @WORKORDER_LOT_ID  
     AND workorder_split_id = @WORKORDER_SPLIT_ID  
     AND workorder_sub_id = @WORKORDER_SUB_ID  
     AND cust_order_id is not NULL  
     update UNP_MNT_CALLS set INVOICE_FLAG = 'R'  
     where  
     workorder_type = @WORKORDER_TYPE  
     AND workorder_base_id = @WORKORDER_BASE_ID  
     AND workorder_lot_id = @WORKORDER_LOT_ID  
     AND workorder_split_id = @WORKORDER_SPLIT_ID  
     AND workorder_sub_id = @WORKORDER_SUB_ID  
     AND cust_order_id is not NULL  
     FETCH LABOR_TICKET_INS INTO  
     @TRANSACTION_ID,  
     @TYPE, @MULTIPLIER_1, @MULTIPLIER_2, @POSTING_CANDIDATE, @SETUP_COMPLETED, @HOURS_WORKED,  
     @WORKORDER_TYPE, @WORKORDER_BASE_ID, @WORKORDER_LOT_ID, @WORKORDER_SPLIT_ID, @WORKORDER_SUB_ID, @OPERATION_SEQ_NO,  
     @GOOD_QTY, @HOURLY_COST, @BAD_QTY, @UNIT_COST,  
     @BURDEN_PERCENT, @BURDEN_PER_HR, @BURDEN_PER_UNIT, @BUR_PER_OPERATION, @TRANSACTION_DATE  
    END  
    DEALLOCATE LABOR_TICKET_INS  
    IF (@nRcd <> 0) RAISERROR('VMFG-%d error in trigger INSERT_LABOR_TICKET', 16, -1, @nRcd)  
    IF (@nRcd <> 0 Or @@ERROR <> 0) ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
```

This the part(from line 154 to 172) of the trigger that I'm unable to figure out why it is not being executed where my logic thinks it should be executing because this statement on line 136 from the trigger is evaluated to be false:

Line 154 - Line 172:

```
 Else  
 update OPERATION set  
 act_atl_lab_cost = act_atl_lab_cost + round(@LaborCost, 2),  
 act_atl_bur_cost = act_atl_bur_cost + round(@BurdenCost, 2),  
 completed_qty = completed_qty + @GOOD_QTY,  
 deviated_qty = deviated_qty + @BAD_QTY,  
 act_setup_hrs = act_setup_hrs + @SetupHrs,  
 act_run_hrs = act_run_hrs + @RunHrs,  
 setup_completed = @SETUP_COMPLETED,  
 status = @STATUS,  
 close_date = @CLOSE_DATE  
 where  
 workorder_type = @WORKORDER_TYPE  
 and workorder_base_id = @WORKORDER_BASE_ID  
 and workorder_lot_id = @WORKORDER_LOT_ID  
 and workorder_split_id = @WORKORDER_SPLIT_ID  
 and workorder_sub_id = @WORKORDER_SUB_ID  
 and sequence_no = @OPERATION_SEQ_NO  
 END
```

Comment: I forgot to add that even if the line 136 of the trigger is evaluated true, it is still not updating the record in the OPERATION table. So there is something that I must be doing incorrectly in my code.

Comment: A **cursor** inside a **trigger** is a sure fire way to kill off any system performance you might have had - **NEVER EVER** do that! You need to write your trigger in a proper, set-based fashion to avoid RBAR (row-by-agonizing-row) processing

Comment: This is a pre existing trigger that someone else wrote and it has been working for longtime without anything being altered.. What I'm trying to do is just to add a record in the LABOR_TICKET table, but I need to get the updates executed as it is written in the trigger. Although I'm able to successfully insert the record, but there may be something that I'm missing in my code, perhaps some other column values, which is causing the trigger not to update the OPERATION table?